# Win32 - Fastest way to determine if file exists in a folder based on a a folders PIDL?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

Using windows/shell api (atl be ok), given a folder's PIDL, what's the fastest way to check if a file exists in that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the *fastest* way, but it is fairly straight-forward:

Convert the `PIDL` to an [`IShellFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder) (if you don't already have one) using [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetdesktopfolder) and [`IShellFolder::BindToObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-bindtoobject), or just [`SHBindToObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbindtoobject), or other related function. And then call the folder's [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-parsedisplayname) (and, if needed,  [`IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-getattributesof)) for the child filename.  If an error occurs, the file does not exist.

Alternatively, convert the `PIDL` to an [`IShellItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) (if you don't already have one) using [`SHCreateItemFromIDList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateitemfromidlist), and then use [`SHCreateItemFromRelativeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateitemfromrelativename) (and, if needed,  [`IShellItem::GetAttributes(SFGAO_VALIDATE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-getattributes)) for the child filename.  Again, if an error occurs (or the attributes don't validate), the file does not exist.